# git add cannot add files which cloning from other git repository to git repository cache

Tags: git

I cloned 3 repo from github and stored in `g://code/`, then create a repo in remote github and in `g://code/` excute:

```
git init 
git add remote origin git@github.com:xxx/xxxx.git     "xxx" is my github username 
git pull origin master

git add . 
git status
```

At that time, I saw the output, find have some files added in the git cache system but have some files not added.

I ignore this problem and write the command

```
git commit -m 'xxx'
git push origin master
```

we browse to my github.com and find some file added to my github repo but some file not.

The problem is： 
The `g://code/` directory has 3 subdirectories after excute the command `git add .` and saw the result of `git status`

I find 1 subdirectory all files added to the git cache but other subdirectories added to the git cache as a single file, the subdirectories files not added into git cache.

I don't know why?

Comment: Are you by any chance in windows, and cloning a repository made in another operating system?

Comment: It sounds like you are expecting your new repository to contain the content of the repositories that you cloned.  That will not happen, since git will not add files from a subdirectory which is linked to a different git repository.  You may want to look into using [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).